# add autoslide with jquery waterwheel

Tags: jquery, html, css

i use plugin jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js to make my image slide manually but i want to know how i can make my image slide alone with jquery and setInterval method. Thank you!!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var carousel = $(".container").waterwheelCarousel({
 flankingItems: 3
  });
  $('#arrow1').bind('click',function(){
    carousel.prev();
    return false;
  });
  $('#arrow2').bind('click',function(){
    carousel.next();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span><img id="slide1" class="slide1" src="./image/slide.jpg" ></span>
    <span><img id="slide2" class="slide2" src="./image/slide2.jpg"></span>
    <span><img id="slide3" class="slide3" src="./image/slide3.jpg"></span>
    <button class="arrow" id="arrow1" onclick="plusIndex(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="arrow" id="arrow2" onclick="plusIndex(1)">&#10095;</button>
 

  </div>

</body>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.waterwheelCarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```